# Need help to simplify the expression involving powers

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}\right)^{24}$$
somehow this should be equal to :$$\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{12}$$
but I can't see how...

Comment: Unequal complex numbers can still have equal $12$th powers.

Comment: The argument of $b=1-(\sqrt{3}-i)/2$ is $(5/12)\pi$, so $b^{24}$ is a positive real number.  Then compute the absolute value.

Comment: Well, $b$ is in the first quadrant, and $\arctan((1/2)/(1-\sqrt3/2))/\pi$ came out $0.416666666$ so I was pretty sure it was $5/12$.

Comment: All this commentary and I'm the only one who's upvoted the question!  (I'm also the only one who's posted a correct answer....)

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Yes, your'e right, that was stupid from my side :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
a=\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2} = \cos 30^\circ-i\sin30^\circ.
$$
Look at the triangle whose vertices are $0$, $a$, and $1$.  Since the distance from $0$ to $1$ and the distance from $0$ to $a$ are both equal to the radius of the unit circle, the triangle is isosceles.  The angle at the center of the circle is $30^\circ$ and the other two angles must be equal to each other.  Since they have to add up to $180^\circ$, they must each be half of the remaining $150^\circ$, hence each $75^\circ$.

The short side of the triangle is just $1-a$.  Hece $1-a=|1-a|(\cos75^\circ+i\sin75^\circ)$.  Now
$$
|1-a|=\left|1-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}\right| = \left|\frac{2-\sqrt{3}-i}{2}\right| = \frac{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}{2} = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}.
$$

Hence
$$
(1-a)^{24} = \left(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)^{24} (\cos(24 \cdot 75^\circ) + i\sin(24 \cdot 75^\circ)) = \left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{12}\cdot(1).
$$
($24\cdot75^\circ=1800^\circ = 5\text{ full circles}$, so the cosine is $1$ and the sine is $0$.)

Comment: (Recall that if $a$, $b$ are real, then $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.  I used that.)

Comment: Of course, an alternative would be to expand via the binomial theorem and then simplify, but that's rather onerous.

Comment: Thankyou @Michael Hardy. Nice way. I am just worried about that -1

Comment: @Mykolas : The $-1$ was there because I mistakenly multiplied by 12 instead of 24.  I've fixed that now.  So could you consider up-voting and possibly "accepting" this answer?

Comment: Thankyou again. Really nice way you made it, man.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$
\left( 1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{3} - i}{2} \right)^{24} = \left[\left( 1 - \dfrac{\sqrt{3} - i}{2} \right)^2\right]^{12}
$$

Comment: I get $\frac{(3-2\sqrt{3})+(2-\sqrt{3})i}{2}$ for the square of the expretion, but I can't see how this helps me...@JavaMan could you explain bit more?

Comment: I also don't see that it helps.  But I've posted a separate answer below.

Comment: @JavaMan : I've down-voted your answer since I don't see that it helps.  I confess to a suspicion: You might have thought that if a certain complex number raised to the 12th power is $(2-\sqrt{3})^{12}$, then that complex number must be $2-\sqrt{3}$.  Is that your whole rationale?  If so, it's really easy to show that $\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}\right)^2$ is _not_ $2-\sqrt{3}$, and in fact it's not even a real number.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: start by squaring $(1-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2})$. Remember that $(a-b)^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2$, and that $i^2=-1$.

Comment: I suggest that _you_ try squaring $1-\frac{\sqrt{3}-i}{2}$ and _then_ tell us whether you think that helps.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to deal with imaginary numbers is with exponentials. This is definitely the case here. First, put everything over a common denominator, then take the exponential. Remember that $(e^{a})^{b} = e^{a*b}$ and $e^{a+b} = e^{a}*e^{b}.$ When you're done simplifying, take the ln of both sides. In the last step, think about what $(-i)^{12}$ equals.

Comment: $(e^a)^b=e^{(ab)}$ but $e^{a^b}$ means $e^{(a^b)}$, not $(e^a)^b$.  And $e^{ab}$ is certainly not the same as $e^a\cdot e^b$, which is equal to $e^{a+b}$.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives the same alternate form for the two given formulas. Both equal 3650401 - 2107560*sqrt(3).

Comment: Turns out this is because the two are the same except for a difference of (10^-19)*i (which may just be due to imprecision in my calculator). So for all intents and purposes they are the same.